# Storing Tenants Cloud Keys In a Database

Tags: encryption, databases, storage, credentials

Imagine you are building a public service where you need to store the customer's cloud credentials(like their aws secret and access keys) in your database to regularly use by your backend services in the background to do things.

What are some of the key risks involved and potential controls which can be implemented to protect unauthorized disclosure of the customers keys?

Comment: Cloud Security Alliance may have some references for you, here is the first hit I got from them: https://blog.cloudsecurityalliance.org/2012/03/12/lock-box-where-should-you-store-cloud-encryption-keys/ ; https://downloads.cloudsecurityalliance.org/initiatives/secaas/SecaaS_Cat_8_Encryption_Implementation_Guidance.pdf